# How to set the default select input value based on database value

Tags: html, forms, coldfusion, default-value, html.dropdownlistfor

Is it possible to set a select inputs default value based on a value returned by a database query? Where below `getFormData.color_it = 'RAL7035TXT'`

```
<cfquery name="getFormData" datasource="RC">
        SELECT      *
        FROM        RFQ_Data
        WHERE       form_ID = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.rfqID#">
    </cfquery>

<select name="color_it">
<option value="RAL9005TXT">RAL9005TXT </option>
<option value="RAL7035TXT">RAL7035TXT </option>
<option value="other">Other </option>
</select>
```

The result I am looking for would change the select so that the option with the value RAL7035TXT would be on top so it is the default. (see below)

```
<select name="color_it">
<option value="RAL7035TXT">RAL7035TXT </option>
<option value="RAL9005TXT">RAL9005TXT </option>
<option value="other">Other </option>
</select>
```

**Would this have to be done with with a lot of if statements?**

Looks like my question was answered in one of my other questions: [ColdFusion how to set form input values from the results of a cfquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764370/coldfusion-how-to-set-form-input-values-from-the-results-of-a-cfquery/29764893#29764893)

Answer (score 0):

You can set default selected value:

```
<select name="color_it">
<option value="RAL7035TXT"selected="selected" >RAL7035TXT </option>
<option value="RAL9005TXT">RAL9005TXT </option>
<option value="other">Other </option>
</select>
```

If you want to use value in the select that is received by the database you can just save the query in a php variable and use this value in the  tag like this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
```

Comment: This thought process would work but I also want to keep the other options in case the user wants to make a change to their previous selection.

Comment: You can put as many <options> as you like and not all must be from the database. What <option value="RAL7035TXT"selected="selected > does is to put this value as a default chosen, but users can still chose another option. If this is not what you meant please say and I will try to help again. 

P.S I've seen that I missed closing "" in my previous code and now have edited it